# R readLines chokes reading from a socketConnection when encoding = "UTF-8"

Tags: r, sockets, utf-8

With chokes I mean readLines simply stops processing and blocks.
How can I get it working for UTF-8?

When I setup a socketConnection
and set encoding = "UTF-8" for the server or the client (or both)
then readLines chokes.
But it works fine when both the server and the client use encoding = "native.enc".

readChar works fine in every setup, no matter which encoding the server and client use.
But it is too slow and I think scan also uses readLines internally
so using readChar is no real option for me.

The sample code (see socket_chockes.zip) defines 8 functions.
I hope the names make clear what they (see code below).
The table shows which combination works (w) and which blocks (b):

```
                    consume_char_native
                      consume_char_utf8
                        consume_lines_native
                          consume_lines_utf8

serve_char_native   w w w b
serve_char_utf8     w w w b
serve_lines_native  w w w b
serve_lines_utf8    b b b b
```

I captured the trafic with RawCap
and can forward it by e-mail
if this is for any help.
You can see that the client stops processing in s1c2
and the server in s2c2.

```
            server.R            client.R
s1c1.pcap:  serve_lines_native  consume_lines_native
s1c2.pcap:  serve_lines_native  consume_lines_utf8
s2c2.pcap:  serve_lines_utf8    consume_lines_utf8
```

My sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1
```

Code server.R

```
make_server_con  <- function(encoding) {
  socketConnection(
    server = TRUE,
    host = "localhost", port = 49125,
    blocking = TRUE, open = "r+", encoding = encoding
  )
}

serve_readLines <- function(con) {
  print(readLines(con, n = 1L))
  print(readLines(con, n = 1L))
  print(readLines(con, n = 1L))
  print(readLines(con, n = 1L))
  writeLines(
    c("0"),
    con = con
  )
}

serve_readChar <- function(con) {
  print(readChar(con, n = 3L))
  print(readChar(con, n = 2L))
  print(readChar(con, n = 8L))
  print(readChar(con, n = 3L))
  writeLines(
    c("0"),
    con = con
  )
}

serve_example <- function(encoding, fun) {
  con <- make_server_con(encoding)
  fun(con)
  fun(con)
  close(con)
}

serve_char_native <- function() {
  serve_example("native.enc", serve_readChar)
}

serve_char_utf8  <- function() {
  serve_example("UTF-8",      serve_readChar)
}

serve_lines_native  <- function() {
  serve_example("native.enc", serve_readLines)
}

serve_lines_utf8  <- function() {
  serve_example("UTF-8",      serve_readLines)
}
```

Code client.R

```
make_client_con  <- function(encoding) {
  socketConnection(
    host = "localhost", port = 49125,
    blocking = TRUE, open = "r+", encoding = encoding
  )
}

consume_readLines <- function(con) {
  writeLines(
    c("ls", "2", "Overall", "de"),
    con = con
  )
  print(readLines(con, n = 1L))
}

consume_readChar <- function(con) {
  writeLines(
    c("ls", "2", "Overall", "de"),
    con = con
  )
  print(readChar(con, n = 2L))
}

consume_example <- function(encoding, fun) {
  con <- make_client_con(encoding)
  fun(con)
  fun(con)
  close(con)
}

consume_char_native <- function() {
  consume_example("native.enc", consume_readChar)
}

consume_char_utf8 <- function() {
  consume_example("UTF-8", consume_readChar)
}

consume_lines_native <- function() {
  consume_example("native.enc", consume_readLines)
}

consume_lines_utf8 <- function() {
  consume_example("UTF-8", consume_readLines)
}
```